# IF, INDEX and MATCH functions to retrieve values with particular keyword

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I want to retrieve the value in cell on active sheet if it matches the corresponding email column and has the keyword `search`. This formula is showing the error `#VALUE!`:

```
IF(INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0)="search");INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0));"Not available")
```

Comment: No it has the email id. 
The other sheet "DATA1" has email ids with corresponding values - search, google display!
I want to extract the value in active cell if they have any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closed parenthesis on the first index/match:

```
=IF(INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0))="search";INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0));"Not available")
```

If you want multiple keywords, then combine them with `Or()`, such as:

```
=If(Or(INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0))="search",INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0))="display"),INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0)),"")
```

But maybe index/match isn't the most optimal way to do what you're trying to get after.  Can you explain a little more (edit your OP), what you're trying to do so we can avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I want to perform this for multiple keywords say  - "search","display" . 



=IF(INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0))="search","google";INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(B13;'DATA 1'!A:A;0));"")

it is still showing again the paranthesis error.

Comment: Also it is not returning the needed value witrh this formula.

Comment: @MukundJha - can you post some sample data/table in your OP? I've edited my post to show how you could look up two keywords (using `Or()`).